# Capturing image without user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to capture a photo in iOS without any user interaction by using the front camera. Can any one show me how to do that?

I used the `takePicture` function in `UIImagePickerController` class but it didn't work because the delegate method `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)`info never get called:

```
-(void)takePicture:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//Use camera if device has one otherwise use photo library
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
else
{
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}

[imagePicker setDelegate:self];

//Show image picker
     [imagePicker takePicture];
}
```

Can anyone show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code

```
//Getting image from front camera
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

[self imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: no that doesn't solve it at all :) 1 line is superfluous, 2 line isn't valid objc